Running conduits and wiring for outdoor decking 120v lights
I would like to add new outdoor lights for a new deck, best and cheapest conduits and wiring to be used, we will need to run from existing wall mounted junction box, under the top deck, holes will drilled on beams to pass conduits and wiring, lights to be used are suitable for Wet Locations, IP67, 120V

Conduits must be electrical rated.  Cannot use pipes for water even if they look almost the same.  Wires must be wet rated and at least minimum gauge for the circuit breaker.  The best/cheapest is shopping we do not do.

Have you considered going with low voltage LED Lighting? Much less code concerns and easier / less expensive to do safely.

"Best" and "cheapest" are often different things. Which do you want? As for cheapest, can't really help as your local cost and my local cost may be different for different things.

What exactly is the question?

This is a classic problem that occurs in many different types of analysis, including products like this situation, but also software development and other things. Typically it is phrased in terms of:

You can have A, B and C. Pick which two you want.

But it is even simpler with "A or B".
In this case, you would like "best" and "cheapest".
Best could, arguably, be rigid metal conduit - the conduit can be used instead of a ground wire and it provides physical protection. On the other hand, it is far from cheapest - currently ~ $29 per 10' 1/2" stick at Home Depot. (Not the best source, but a useful basis for comparison of different product types.)
On the other hand, you could get 25' of 1/2" ENT (a.k.a., "smurf tube"). That won't provide physical protection, so depending on location it may need additional protection (e.g., wood or metal). But it is a lot cheaper at ~ $16 for 25' at Home Depot.
There are other types of conduit - both metal and plastic - with varying attributes of cost, flexibility (ENT can bend to go anywhere, most other types require special tools to bend them or using various angled connectors), grounding, physical protection, aesthetics (matters to some people if the conduit is visible), etc.
My recommendation is to look at the different possibilities and then make a decision based on all the factors as well as your budget, length of conduit (spending an extra $1 per foot is a big deal on 100' but not on 6'), etc.
